# How can i execute the soql in apex in the salesforce developer console? plz help me!

Tags: apex, developer-console

I made a apex class named "FilteredTableControllerTest". 
and I want to execute this class so that i put `FilteredTableControllerTest.testCases();` 
Debug > Open Excute Anonymous Window > Enter Apex Code 
But It gave me the error message like "Line: 1, Column: 29 
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void testCases() from the type FilteredTableControllerTest" 
How can i execute the class?

```
public with sharing class FilteredTableControllerTest {
        @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
            public static List<Pkg_Summary__c> testCases(integer exDimWidth, integer exDimWidthRange){
                return [SELECT 
                            ID, Name, LoadSizeLength__c, LoadSizeWidth__c,  LoadEfficiency__c,
                            TotalLoadSizeHeight__c, TotalLoadWeight__c, MinimumSafetyFactor__c
                        from Pkg_Summary__c 
                        where 
                            TotalLoadSizeHeight__c > : (exDimWidth + exDimWidthRange)
                            and TotalLoadSizeHeight__c < : (exDimWidth - exDimWidthRange)
                        ];                                                                                                                     
        }

        @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
            public static List<Pkg_Component__c> getPacking(integer exWidth, integer exWidthRange){
                return [SELECT 
                                Name, PkgCategory__c, PkgDetailItems__c, MaterialName__c, DocumentStatus__c, PkgStatus__c,
                                Width__c, Length__c, Height__c, EM_Space__c, RollWidth__c, GadgetFoldingWidth__c, 
                                Planar_Length__c, Planar_Width__c
                            from Pkg_Component__c 
                            where 
                                Width__c < : (exWidth + exWidthRange)
                                and Width__c > : (exWidth - exWidthRange)
                            ];                                                                                                                     
        }

    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the error is correct, since the signature of the method is different.

You need to pass the parameters of the method as well while calling it (integer exDimWidth, integer exDimWidthRange)

Like this :

```
Integer exDimWidthValue = 5; //example value, enter your values
Integer exDimWidthRangeValue = 7;
FilteredTableControllerTest.testCases(exDimWidthValue, exDimWidthRangeValue);
```

Comment: Thank for answering! I did it. but i took the error message like " Variable does not exist: exDimWidth"

Comment: You need to send the values as the parameter, I'll edit my asnwer

Comment: Yes! It works! Thanks a lot!